# Run program that is not in the same folder

Tags: vb.net

I need some help here, thanks, I am currently making a project in VB.net. What I want is that when you press a button, it will launch a program. So let's say that my program is called "test.exe" and the file is placed in "C:\Users\user\desktop\test.exe". How do I attach a code to a button that will RUN this program? Thankyou so much. Sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: yes this is a bad question

Comment: may be you should use relative path.. just a suggestion

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the bad question, I am new here, if you see that :(

Comment: This question will likely be closed because it is too hard to tell what it is you have already tried, and what you are stuck on. You might like to have a look at this, which may be helpful to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbfaq/archive/2004/05/30/144573.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Process.Start("C:\Users\user\desktop\test.exe", "Arguments here")`

**UPDATE**

if your `main.exe` is in `xyz` folder and your `test.exe` is in folder outside `xyz` say `abc` then use

```
Process.Start("xyz\..\abc\test.exe", "Arguments here")
```

This is relative path *Note that both `xyz` and `abc` have same parent*

Comment: Thankyou! I appreciate your response :)

Comment: Also, I am new at this language, let's say, I have a folder, called "MyFolder", in this folder, there is my Project and test.exe, when someone else is getting "MyFolder" they can't press the button "C:\Users\user\desktop\test.exe" because thats just for my account, do you know how to make this code like when pressing the button, it will launch the program in the same folder, that was actually my question, but I am bad at explaining, thanks, like pressing the button then the code "Process.Start("MyFolder\test.exe")" will run. Does that code work?

Comment: you are really bad at explaining :p `because thats just for my account` what does this mean???

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
Public Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles someButton.Click
    Process.Start("C:\Users\user\desktop\test.exe") 'You can also pass arguments by overloading this method like:
    Process.Start("C:\Users\user\desktop\test.exe", "foo argument")
End Sub
```